# EJB Module that consumes messages from MULTIPLE Remote Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

i'm creating an EJB module that consumes messages from a remote server; I'm using this code:

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/Topic", activationConfig =  {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "addressList", propertyValue = "192.168.31.10" )
, @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
, @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic")
```

}

and it works. 
Now I would receive from multiple remote servers; I'm thinking something like this:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "addressList", propertyValue = "192.168.31.10 , 192.168.31.11 , 192.168.31.12" )
```

but it doesn't work.

What is the right method?

Answer (score 1):

Each MDB is bound to listen to a single resource at a time.

As a workaround, you can try configuring it in deployment descriptor file, where a single MDB will be configured to listen multiple remote topics.

Excerpt from Weblogic documentation for MDB:

> If your application requires a single JMS consumer to service messages
>   from multiple Queues or Topics, you must use a standard JMS consumer,
>   or deploy multiple message-driven bean classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create multiple MDB-s and then forward their incoming messages to the same business component. So your MDB-s don't really process anything, just collect messages.